# Нужно ли ставить запятую перед "как" в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли ставить запятую перед "как" в данных предложениях?

*Я хочу относиться к тебе(,) как к самому ценному человеку в моей жизни.*

*Я бы общался с тобой(,) как со своим братом.*

Answer (score 2):

Во втором примере запятая нужна, потому что он же не брат, с братом сравнивается.
Розенталь:
Примечание. Некоторые предложения допускают двоякую пунктуацию в зависимости от их истолкования; ср.:
*Я относился к нему как к брату* — ‘он мне брат’.
*Я относился к нему, как к брату* — ‘по-братски’, ‘**он мне не брат**’.

В первом примере, думаю, тоже запятая нужна. "В качестве" не очень подходит. Ощущается сравнение.